# Derive a reduction formula for an improper integral $\int_{0}^{1} x^3(\ln x)^n \, dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

> Derive a reduction formula for $I_{n} = \int_{0}^{1} x^3(\ln x)^n \, dx$ 
>   and hence evaluate $I_4$.

My workings:

I noted that as the $f(x)$ has a $\ln(x)$ term in it and the lower limit is $0$, there is an infinite discontinuity at $x=0$.

Hence, this integral becomes $$\lim_{t\to 0}\int_{t}^{1} x^3(\ln x)^n \, dx$$

I tried to do integration by parts once and realised the first term, $x^{3}$, reduced to $x^{2}$, so I performed it twice more to obtain

$$\left[ \frac {1}{4}x^4(\ln x)^n \right]_{t}^{1} - n \left[ \frac {1}{3}x^3(\ln x)^n-1 \right]_{t}^{1} + n(n^2-n) \left[ \frac {1}{2}x^2(\ln x)^n-2 \right]_{t}^{1} - (n-3) I_{n-3}$$

I am unsure of how to carry on as the (I am unsure of how to evaluate the limit for this) or if I had made a mistake in my approach.

Comment: Since the logarithm grows slowly, the integrand in fact has the limit $0$ at $0$. Hence the boundary terms in the integration by parts nicely vanish until the end.

Comment: for $I_1$ i got $$-\frac{1}{16}$$ and $I_2=\frac{1}{32}$

Comment: Sorry, I am still a little confused what do you mean by the integration terms will vanish until the end. 
How do I obtain the reduction formula $I_n$ since I note that the integral is actually contains limit and $ln(1)=0,ln(0)=\infty$ which makes the limits situation complicated. I am have problems evaluating the reduction formula which from what I have tried to solve , is a really long string limit.

Comment: For every $\alpha > 0$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $$\lim_{x\to 0} x^{\alpha}\cdot \lvert \ln x\rvert^{\beta} = 0.$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: substitute $\ln{x}=t$ and rewrite the integral, you will find a much easier form to handle

Comment: For substitution of $lnx=t$,  when $x=0, t=\infty, x=1, t=0$ and $dx=e^t dt$ so you mean to solve for $ \int_{-\infty}^{0} (e^t)^2(t^n) \, dt  $ ?

Comment: you need to to convert $dx$ in form of $t$ and you will have an integral.

Comment: Thanks, I will attempt to solve the limits for this form.

Comment: @dormacus you need to multiply $e^t$ rather than divide. $x=e^t$ therefore $dx=e^tdt$

Answer (score 1):

You may consider that
$$ \int_{0}^{1}x^3\left(\log x\right)^n\,dx = \frac{d^n}{d\alpha^n}\int_{0}^{1}x^{3+\alpha}\,dx =\frac{d^n}{d\alpha^n}\left(\frac{1}{4+\alpha}\right)=\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(4+\alpha)^{n+1}}\tag{A}$$
hence by evaluating at $\alpha=0$ you get
$$ \frac{I_{n+1}}{I_n} = -\frac{n+1}{4},\qquad I_4=\frac{4!}{4^5}=\frac{3}{2^7}.\tag{B}$$

Comment: (+1) for the technique, though this may be a little advanced for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

We are going to prove the general formula for the integral
$$\boxed{\int_{0}^{1} x^{a}(\ln x)^{n} d x=\frac{(-1)^{n} n !}{(a+1)^{n+1}}}$$
where $n\in N$ and $a\not=-1$.

By defining
$$
\begin{aligned}
J(a) &:=\int_{0}^{1} x^{a} d x =\left[\frac{x}{a+1}\right]_{0}^{1} =\frac{1}{a+1}
\end{aligned}
$$
Differentiating $J(a)$ w.r.t $a$ by $n$ times on both sides yields $$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d^{n}}{d a^{n}}(J(a))&=\frac{d^{n}}{d a^{n}}\left(\frac{1}{a+1}\right) \\
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\partial^{n}}{\partial a^{n}}\left(x^{a}\right) d x&=\frac{(-1)^{n} n !}{(a+1)^{n+1}} \\
\int_{0}^{1} x^{a}(\ln x)^{n} d x&=\frac{(-1)^{n} n !}{(a+1)^{n+1}},
\end{aligned}
$$
In particular, putting $a=3$ gives $$
\boxed{\int_{0}^{1} x^{3}(\ln x)^{n} d x=\frac{(-1)^{n} n !}{4^{n+1}}}
$$